# Is there a way to look at windows logs and uninstall previously installed software?

Tags: windows-10, event-log

I installed a software with a custom installer, so it didn't log it in the application tab. The software installed third-party software which I am trying to remove. However, I don't know what other stuff it installed. That is why I am looking if windows has made any logs of the installation.

I am running windows 10 1909

Comment: If you have a disk, compare the likely app locations (Program Files, Program Files (X86), AppData, etc.) for changes, or just restore the image.